# Passing values from page1.php to page2.php using sessions

Tags: php, html

I would like to pass values from page1.php to page2.php using session variable. However, i am yet to be successfull. Instead of displaying only one name (the clicked one) on page2.php, all the names from page1.php are displayed. Here is my code,

**page1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$name_data = array();
?>
<?php 
include('dbase.php');

// get the records from the database
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE categoryname='Humanities' ORDER BY noteid"))
{
// display records if there are records to display
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{  
?>
<div class="vdo-list">

<div class="vdo-title"><a href="preview.php">
<?php
$name_data[] = $row->notename;
echo "<h3>" .$row->notename. "</h3>";
?>
</div></a>
<?
$_SESSION['uname'] = $name_data;
?>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
  <div class="heading6">
        <h1>
        <?php
        if(count($_SESSION['uname'])>0)
        {
        foreach ($_SESSION['uname'] as $uname)
        {
        echo $uname;
        }
        }     
        ?>
        </h1></div>
```

Could anyone please point out what i am doing wrong? Any efforts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: session is not necessary here you can use $_GET method you can pass data easily from one page to another page using get method.

Comment: @Bhavin Thank you. Kindly specify where i should replace the session variable with the get variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, here is an answer that works perfectly,

**page1.php**

```
 <?php
$_SESSION['uname'] = $row->notename;
echo '<h3><a href="preview.php?name='.$row->notename.'">'.$row->notename.'<h3></a>';
?>
```

**page2.php**

```
 <?php
include ('dbase.php');
       if(count($_SESSION['uname'])>0)
    {
        if($uname = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `notename`='".$_GET['name']."'"))
        {
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($uname,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   // $result=$uname->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //foreach ($result as $row)
    //{
    echo $row['notename'];
    //}
    }    
    } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't need to save in session all the results. You can succeed what you want querying and selecting at the second page only the row you want using `$_GET`.

For what you are using here, assuming that the link which clicked has the parameter '`name`' you can check at the session array and show only this item:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['uname'] as $uname) {
    if ($uname == $_GET['name']) {
        echo $uname;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Passing parameter in link. In a loop you can add:

```
echo '<a href="page2.php?name='.$row->notename.'">'.$row->notename.'</a>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. I am very green to php so if you would kindly show me how to add the parameter to the link it would be very helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not solve the problem. I get 'undefined index $uname errors'. Thank you for the try though.

Comment: Replace $uname with $row->notename and try again. You have to customize it a bit.

Comment: The variable uname is used severally. Which one do you suggest i replace?

Comment: The one in the loop while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) which will create the links.

Comment: I get this error >    Invalid argument supplied for foreach().